# Equivalent metrics on $\Bbb N$

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

> Show that $(\Bbb N,d_1)$ and $(\Bbb N,d_2)$ are equivalent where $d_1$ is the discrete metric and $d_3(m,n)=|\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}|$.

**My account**

In order to show that $(\Bbb N,d_1)$ and $(\Bbb N,d_2)$ are equivalent,take any $x\in \Bbb N$ and consider $B_{d_1}(x,r)$ .We need to find $s>0$ such that $x\in B_{d_3}(x,s)\subset B_{d_1}(x,r)$ and vice versa.

If we choose $s=r$ in the first case then if $y\in B_{d_1}(x,s)\implies d_1(x,y)<s\implies |x-y|<s\implies |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|<s\implies y\in B_{d_3}(x,r)$.

But I am stuck in the other subset inequality.Please help .

Is there any other way to solve this ?